# WinForms App w/BackgroundWorker & Class Object Events

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I'm working on a WinForms application that does a bunch of File Processing.  This processing is done in multiple class objects that have "events" to publish different types of messages.  One type is a "status" of what is being worked on and Two is an "output" that documents issues or change that were made.

I added a BackgroundWorker process and have that working fine but the only notifications I see is a ProgressPercentage.  If I subscribe & raise any of the class events I get a "Cross-thread operation .. " which is understandable.  What is the best way to implement this so that these components can be used by a winforms app and a non interactive process as well?

Here is what my DoWork looks like now, but the events cause the "Cross-thread":

```
var search = SearchToolFactory.Get(Convert.ToInt32(checkedTypeButton.Tag));

search.RaiseUpdateSearchEvent += new EventHandler<UpdateEventArgs>(search_RaiseUpdateSearchEvent);
search.RaiseUpdateOutputEvent += new EventHandler<UpdateEventArgs>(search_RaiseUpdateOutputEvent);
search.Process(Convert.ToInt32(checkedScopeButton.Tag), txtInput.Text, txtPattern.Text);
```

And here is the UpdateEventArgs, just a smilple class to pass a message:

```
public class UpdateEventArgs: EventArgs
{
    public UpdateEventArgs(string s)
    {
        update = s;
    }
    private string update;
    public string Update
    {
        get { return update; }
        set { update = value; }
    }
}
```

So based on PMF's comment I got the following to work:

```
void search_RaiseUpdateOutputEvent(object sender, UpdateEventArgs e)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
         this.Invoke( (MethodInvoker)delegate{ txtOutput.Text += e.Update; });
    }

}

void search_RaiseUpdateSearchEvent(object sender, UpdateEventArgs e)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
         this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { txtSearching.Text = e.Update; });
    }

}
```

But also see and understand the concern Hans Passant stated about structural issues and that my architecture is flawed and still needs additional work.

Thanks

dbl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `Invoke()` any user-interface event from your background-worker thread. Or you invoke the actual update in the form code (the later solution is probably the nicer way because it keeps the UI logic to the UI part of the application).

That would look similar to the following (for an event handler listening to status changes):

```
public void OnStatusUpdated(Status newStatus)
{
     if (InvokeRequired)
     {
         Invoke(delegate
            {
                statusControl.Text = newStatus.ToString(); // Or something like it.
            });
     }
}
```

Comment: If as I understand it this would be on the object being called in the DoWork method, it is ignorant of text controls and I was to keep it that way.  If I'm misunderstanding maybe the code I've added to my question can help both of us.

Comment: See the above answer. That would be the implementation of `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged`.

Answer (score 2):

BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress() has an overload with *two* arguments.  The second can be *anything* you want.  Like a delegate:

```
    public event EventHandler Foo;

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
        //...
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, new Action(() => {
            var handler = Foo;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }));
        //...
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
        if (e.UserState != null) ((Action)e.UserState)();
        else this.progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;   // optional
    }
```

Comment: I've added some code to make it a little clearer but I don't see how I can pass a delegate like this that would then catch the appropriate event, but I will confess delegates are not my strong suite.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with "catching" events, only with raising them.

Comment: Then I still don't understand how this helps.  The events occur in a totally separate class than the DoWork.  I've added some code in my original question.

Comment: This answer is based on the assumption that you want to raise events from a background worker and fix the bug where the event handler bombed with an exception.  Which requires raising the event on the UI thread instead of the worker.  The code I showed accomplishes that.  Try it.

Comment: Ok, then I need some help making the connection.  The "event" occurs in a separate code space(class) and is raised there.  I can't move that to the DoWork method.  And if there is some way so subscribe to that event with a delegate I'm not seeing it with the code you've given.

Comment: If the code that raises the event is completely disconnected from the worker then you have no other option but to have the event handlers themselves deal with the problem.  They have to use this.BeginInvoke().  Do keep in mind that there are several structural problems with code running wild, like the user closing the window but the threaded code not quitting and continuing to raise events.  This will end poorly.